# DexExpress TextEdit Different Length / Limit for Visible Text and Edit Value

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, devexpress, textedit

I am using **DevExpress** `TextEdit` for password field on **WinForm**. I want to limit the visible text length limited to few characters only while Actual password length limit is much longer than that. Like may be visible text length is 10 and max password which can be choosen by a user can have 20 characters. User should be able to enter 20 character long password but the character being displayed on form should be only 10 by max. This will enhance visual security of the password.

For Exmaple
Password: abcd1234wxyz4321 (Length 16 Characters)
Text Shown on TextEdit: XXXXXXXXXX (Length 10 Characters)

I have tried setting `TextEdit.Properties.MaxLength` property but thats the max length limit which can be entered by Max. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the functionality you're looking for is present.  You could get the desired effect though by using the Key* events and checking the length of the current entry and just building the full password in a variable while limiting what get's put in the TextEdit control beyond you're required length.

Comment: This functionality is not available by default and need to handle it via Keys events. But problem is how to handle escape characters especially if it is in middle of password. Let say he has entered abcd1234xyz789 we have this in variable but he want to remove 'd', we have d in variable but in text box. So this might cause problem

Comment: Once you're handling the individual keystrokes, you don't care what's in the textbox at all, it's just for show that the user is actually typing.  Honestly, I'd not worry about how many characters are displayed, as at best you're getting security through obscurity.  The goal should be security through policy/protocol, so it doesn't matter if someone shoulder surfs to see how many keys a potential target uses for a password.